# MSSQL Server SPN Connections: Linux to MSSQL Server (setspn, kinit, kerberos authentication)

Tags: sql-server, linux, active-directory, odbc, kerberos

After AD Admin added a SQL server SPN using the setspn tool, the linux server is not able to use the SPN using MS SQL Server ODBC Driver 18 with error "[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSPI Provider: Server not found in Kerberos database"

I have a working kerberos based authentication to one server (dev), and I am trying to implement the same connection setup to a new server (rel). To configure dev, my AD admin set the server SPN using the SPN setting tool:

```
setspn -S MSSQLSvc/dev:dev_sql_port domain\dev_service_user
```

And we can verify that the spn has been created using

```
setspn -Q MSSQLSvc/dev*
```

There are many domain controlers on the ad domain (7 or so, as determined by using the command `adcli info domain.org` from linux server). At first we were not able to connect to dev using ODBC, but after a few months the following pattern started to work:

```
kinit
Password for user@domain.org: ********
```

Followed by a connection using the connection string:

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=dev;Trusted_Connection=yes;Encrypt=No;TrustServerCertificate=yes
```

The AD admin duplicated everything from the dev setup for rel, using the correct information for the rel sql server instance. I am able to use the following to initialize a kerberos ticket for the new server:

```
kinit -S "MSSQLSvc\rel:rel_port"
Password for user@domain.org: ********
```

However, the python pattern:

```
cnxn_str = ("Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=rel;Trusted_Connection=yes;Encrypt=No;TrustServerCertificate=yes")
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
```

Gives error:

```
Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSPI Provider: Server not found in Kerberos database (851968) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

There are minimal changes to the krb5.conf configuration besides top section:

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = domain.org
        dns_lookup_realm = true
        dns_lookup_kdc = true
```

I have access to appropriate admins to make changes that are researched, however, we (I) am at a bit of a loss why dev works, why it took several months for dev to work, and why rel does not work (yet). It has been 2 weeks since we made the changes to rel.

Comment: Need the whole krb5.conf, please.

Comment: Thanks T-Heron. Updated krb5.conf to only include the above lines with no changes in behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, we determined that there was a typo in the original rel setspn statement, and that there were two listed under `setspn -L realm\rel_sql_service_account` one with the incorrect port, and one with no port. We used the commands

```
setspn -D MSSQLSvc/rel.domain:wrong_port realm\rel_sql_service_account
setspn -D MSSQLSvc/rel.domain realm\rel_sql_service_account
setspn -S MSSQLSvc/rel.domain:right_port realm\rel_sql_service_account
```

There is chance this was done from a command window on a different windows server than where it was originally set. Double checking that was all the same.

Comment: Hi Tim - since two days have passed, please click the Green check mark to signpost it to others as resolved.